# `invalid csrf token` error when using csrf-csrf

Tags: node.js, token, csrf, csrf-token

I face an issue when I am using `csrf-csrf` to replace `csurf`. The token was generated successfully. But once I submit a form, it shows the error `invalid csrf token`:

My code :

in app.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = generateToken(res);
  console.log(res.locals.csrfToken);
  next();
});
```

in view:

```
<form class="login-form" action="/signup" method="POST">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>" >
   <button class="btn" type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

When I click Signup. the error shows up.

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at doubleCsrf (/workspace/nodejs-practice/node_modules/csrf-csrf/lib/cjs/index.cjs:18:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/nodejs-practice/app.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

Any idea about this?
Thank you guys!

update:

I checked the source code of `csrf-csrf`. I find out it gets the token from request by

```
getTokenFromRequest = (req) => req.headers["x-csrf-token"]
```

In my case, it will be undefined. So how can I add the token into the request headers?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by rewrite the `getTokenFromRequest` in doubleCsrf().

```
const {
  generateToken, // Use this in your routes to provide a CSRF hash cookie and token.
  doubleCsrfProtection, // This is the default CSRF protection middleware.
} = doubleCsrf({
  getSecret: () => "my secret",
  getTokenFromRequest: (req) => {
    return req.body._csrf;
  },
});
```

I have to say I still have a long way to go to be a good developer.

Hope this helps others.

**Don't be afraid to read the source code, maybe you'll find it's not as mysterious and difficult to understand as you thought**